# I want a "Go on to next page" arrow where text is inscribed in arrow

Tags: arrows, decorations

I was wondering how i can create an arrow that says embedded "Go on to next page"
the arrow should be something like the implies arrow or the rightarrow.

Comment: have you seen [comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)

Answer (score 8):

Using the `shapes` library from [PGF/TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) you can easily produce some fancy arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  test1/.style={signal, draw, text=white, signal to=nowhere},
  test2/.style={single arrow, draw=none}]
  \node[test1,fill=magenta!40!black, signal to=east] at (0,0) {Go on to next page};
  \node [test2,fill=red!50] at (0,-1.2) {Go on to next page} ; 
  \node [test2,fill=blue!50, single arrow head indent=1ex] at (0,-2.4) {Go on to next page};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, once you've decided the kind of arrow you want to use, you can build a macro to obtain the arrow; something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text

\newcommand\GoArrow{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[signal, draw, text=white, signal to=nowhere,fill=magenta!40!black, signal to=east,anchor=east] 
    at ($ (current page.south east) + (-2,2) $) {Go on to next page};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]
\GoArrow

\end{document}
```

and the lower portion of the page produced:

[image]

Comment: also, tikz provides a "current page" node, this is very useful for absolutely positioning an arrow such as this near the bottom right of a page consistently and quickly.

Comment: @grizzilus: yes, that's what I implied with my last remark, but you're right, I will make it explicit with an example.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose what you want is text over the arrow indicating "Go to Next Page". If that is the case then you can try:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
 \begin{document}
 $\xrightarrow{\text{Go on to next page}}$
 \end{document}
```

Ouput:

[image]